# How to join 'include' in a html-document

Tags: php, html, css, include

I am trying to join the the footer-document to the index-file. But it does not work and I suspect there i something wrong with my css-file.

```css
html {background: url("bakgrund.gif");} 
/*https://pixabay.com/ Gratis bilder Creative Commons CC0*/
html {  overflow-y: scroll;}


body  {
    background: white;
 border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    font-family: calibri, arial, sans-serif;
 width: 750px;
 margin: 25px auto;
 padding: 0;

}
header {
 height: 175px;
 background-color: #edffff;
 margin-top: -16px;
 padding: 0;
} 

nav {
 height: 35px;
 background-color: #edffff;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

section {
 width: 550px;
 float: left;
 min-height: 400px;

}

article {
 width: 550px;
 float: left;
 background-color: yellow;
}

aside {
 width: 200px;
 float: right;
 background-color: lightgrey;
}

footer {
 clear: both;
 position: relative;
 height: 55px;
 padding: 5px ;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: magenta;
} 

address {
 font-size: 12px;
 font-style: normal;
} 

/* Menykataloger */


ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}


#meny li {
display: inline;
padding: 5px 1px;
}

#meny li a {
margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
padding: 5px 15px;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
background: yellow;
}

#meny li a:hover {
background: #CCEBFF;
color: black;
}

#meny a:link, #meny a:visited {
color: black; 
text-decoration: none;
}

#meny a:active {
color: white; 
}

#meny a#current {
background: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stil.css" type="text/css">
 </head>
<body>

<nav>
<ul id="meny">
<li><a href="index.html" id="current">Hem</a></li>
<li><a href="#">AAA</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BBB</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CCC</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<section>
<h2>Huvudrubrik</h2>
<p>Huvudinnehåll</p>

 <article>
 <h2>Rubrik 1</h2>
 <p> Innehåll 1 med rubriker</p>
 </article>

 <article>
 <h2>Rubrik 2</h2>
 <p> Innehåll 2 med rubriker
 </p>
 </article>

</section>  
 
<aside>
Nyhetsbrev H-spalt
</aside>

<?php include("fot.php"); ?>
```

The result is wrong with the interpretation of the border. It just encircles the head and not the whole area.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand what you are trying to do, but your problem is due to `float: left` for `section` tag. There are many alternatives to float like `flex` and `grid`,, so don't prefer float. It will cause many problems. Your problem is listed [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-3).

There is no problem with your php.

Answer (score 0):

I Get your problem 
why dont you start your file with < ? php at begining and close it at the end
instead which you've used like this => "< ? php include("fot.php");" ?> at the end of your second file if you can see.
and save the main html file with the extension .php
trust me nothing will happen to your html code all the html contents will run fine even if you save the file in .php

and the second thing is you can include in two ways 
i.e 
include 'filename';

or

require 'filename';  you better include at the starting of the file 
who would know if that included file may come to use right from the begining

Thanking you!